# Highcharts Flags omits/crops the last point

Tags: highcharts

**With the Highcharts release after 6.0.7, the flags do not adjust itself in the last point. When there is a high number of points I can't see the flags until I zoom in and moreover the flag in the first and last point gets cropped.**

```
1. https://jsfiddle.net/bvinoth/xhd03y75/
Latest Release (after 6.0.7)
```

[Flags are getting cropped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CddFA.png)

```
2. https://jsfiddle.net/bvinoth/jLaspgw1/ 
6.0.7 ( Works fine with all flags)
```

[Flags are not getting cropped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOLzn.png)

As you can see from the first fiddle that the last flag gets cropped and doesn't adjust itself like the way it does in the second fiddle. I have tried various options within the flag series but can't find the one that will give the same result as the second fiddle.

Comment: I [edited your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing), improving either its formatting, or [its quality](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/02/05/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/) to help people understanding your question, and to help you to get an appropriate answer.
But you still may need to add further information for your question to become fully solvable.

Comment: Could add working examples (jsfiddle links) and describe your problem more precisely?